# query limit issue with php and mysql (drupal 6)

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

hi i was trying to do a query in drupal which selects every row in table, i was having an issue with the no of rows i was able to query for the query is working for 300row limit but if i increase it 400 it is going blank page.

```
$total_terms = 300;
$query = "SELECT N.nid ,N.tid FROM term_node N  ";
$query_result = db_query_range($query, $vid, 0, $total_terms);
```

Comment: Exact duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527345

Comment: Also, the last time you asked this, 100 worked but 190 didn't work. Why the change?

Comment: SELECT N.nid ,N.tid FROM term_node N JOIN term_data S ON S.tid = N.tid AND S.vid = 1" 
to
SELECT N.nid ,N.tid FROM term_node N

Comment: What version of Drupal is this?

Comment: I'd normally object the shouting, but in this case it seems necessary ;)

Comment: i am getting child pid 2652 exit signal Segmentation fault (11) in apache log

Answer (score 3):

You are probably [timing out](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), or exceeding your [memory limit](http://drupal.org/node/207036). Check the Apache and PHP logs.

Comment: i have increased the memory to 96mb but still same problem.

Comment: how long before it goes blank? if it is about 30 seconds it is most likely the time limit.

Comment: i am getting child pid 2652 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
in apache log

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [Batch API](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/batch)

It might be helpful to use the [drupal_tweaks](http://drupal.org/project/drupal_tweaks) module; it allows you to set php execution time limit, as well as mysql default_wait limit.